# Setting YouTubePlayerView as overlay on camera Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-camera, zbar

I am using ZBar and the qrcode is scanning.

But while the camera is open I want the video to play using YouTubePlayerView to be overlayed on top of camera.

Any idea how can I do this?

For any more info please comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [tutor](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html) on overlaying layout over camera. And you add either YoutubePlayerView or YoutubeFragment view on it further to play the video.